# Using a System.Drawing.Font with a WPF Label

Tags: wpf, fonts, label, underline

I have a WPF Label control which I'm trying to change the appearance of using a System.Drawing.Font object supplied by some legacy code. I have been able to set most of the properties, but am struggling with Strikeout and Underline.

So far I have:

```
System.Drawing.Font font = FontFromLegacyCode();

System.Windows.Controls.Label label = new System.Windows.Controls.Label();
label.FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily( font.Name );
label.FontWeight = font.Bold ? System.Windows.FontWeights.Bold : System.Windows.FontWeights.Regular;
label.FontStyle = font.Italic ? System.Windows.FontStyles.Italic : System.Windows.FontStyles.Normal;
label.FontSize = font.Size;
```

How do you set the font strikeout or underline properties? Is there a better control to use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would change it to a TextBlock control. The TextBlock control has the TextDecorations property you can use.

```
<TextBlock Name="textBlock" TextDecorations="Underline, Strikethrough" />
```

Or you can stick a TextBlock inside a Label if you really like (although I'd just use the TextBlock by itself).

```
<Label Name="label">
    <TextBlock Name="textBlock" TextDecorations="Underline, Strikethrough" />
</Label>
```

Have a look at the [TextDecorations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.textdecorations.aspx) class.

I find that TextBlocks are more suitable than Labels in most situations. Here's a [blog post](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/) about the differences. The chief difference being that a Label is a Control whereas a TextBlock is just a FrameworkElement. Also a Label supports access keys.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I should have been using a TextBlock in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you already have, there might be a problem with it.
On the MSDN on [Windows Form and WPF Property mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751565.aspx) they make the comment:

> Font size in WPF is expressed as one ninety-sixth of an inch, and in Windows Forms as one seventy-second of an inch. The corresponding conversion is:
>
> Windows Forms font size = WPF font size * 72.0 / 96.0.

Comment: Because i just used this, also if you are using WPF in a WinForms element host, you can change the size as `(FontSize * 96)/72`.  That's if you have a stored font size in a windows form environment, and need to translate that to a WPF FontSize for a hosted WPF control like a textblock or textbox.