# Changing Label properties programmatically

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, label

The problem is that I need to change Label FontWeight and FontStyle programmatically but nothing seems to work... this is what I've tried so far:

```
label.FontWeight = FontWeight.FromOpenTypeWeight(99);
```

For label.FontStyle I have no idea, I got stuck here:

```
label.FontStyle = new FontStyle();
```

I have no idea what to do from there on. I googled like crazy but found nothing.

Thanks in advance for any suggestion!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For FontStyle you can use the FontStyles class in the code-behind, and for FontWeight use the FontWeights.

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        uiLabel.FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
        uiLabel.FontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637636/using-a-system-drawing-font-with-a-wpf-label).  It doesn't help with the label, per se, but it does allow you to change properties of the text using a TextBlock control.