# WPF - TextBlock - Format Text Programmatically

Tags: wpf, xaml, styles

In the TextBlock object you can format the text in the XAML like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Bold>bold text</Bold> random non bold next
</TextBlock>
```

How do you do the "Bold" tags programmatically?

I tried just putting them in the text property and it just printed them out (the tags were printed as text).

Comment: Thanks for both the great answers.  Upvoted both.  Picked the one I did because it was specific to my example.

Comment: More better solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947614/changing-label-properties-programmatically

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Visual Basic Version:

```
Dim tb As New TextBlock

Dim b As New Bold
b.Inlines.Add(New Run("bold text"))

tb.Inlines.Add(b)
tb.Inlines.Add(New Run("random non bold text"))
```

C# Version:

```
TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
var bold = new Bold(new Run("Bold Text"));
tb.Inlines.Add(bold);

var normal = new Run("Normal Text"));
tb.Inlines.Add(normal);
```

Comment: Does anybody know a way like

    tb.Inlines.Clear();
    tb.Inlines.Add(Parse(myXamlText));

</code>
?

Answer (score 21):

Here is the code from the MSDN website, which I think will help (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.aspx).

XAML

```
<TextBlock Name="textBlock1" TextWrapping="Wrap">
  <Bold>TextBlock</Bold> is designed to be <Italic>lightweight</Italic>,
  and is geared specifically at integrating <Italic>small</Italic> portions
  of flow content into a UI.
</TextBlock>
<Button Width="100" Margin="10">Click Me</Button>
<TextBlock  Name="textBlock2" 
  TextWrapping="Wrap" Background="AntiqueWhite" TextAlignment="Center"
>
  By default, a TextBlock provides no UI beyond simply displaying its contents.
</TextBlock>
<Button Width="100" Margin="10">Click Me</Button>
```

C#

```
TextBlock textBlock1 = new TextBlock();
TextBlock textBlock2 = new TextBlock();

textBlock1.TextWrapping = textBlock2.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;
textBlock2.Background = Brushes.AntiqueWhite;
textBlock2.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;

textBlock1.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("TextBlock")));
textBlock1.Inlines.Add(new Run(" is designed to be "));
textBlock1.Inlines.Add(new Italic(new Run("lightweight")));
textBlock1.Inlines.Add(new Run(", and is geared specifically at integrating "));
textBlock1.Inlines.Add(new Italic(new Run("small")));
textBlock1.Inlines.Add(new Run(" portions of flow content into a UI."));

textBlock2.Text =
    "By default, a TextBlock provides no UI beyond simply displaying its contents.";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textBlock1.FontWeight = Windows.UI.Text.FontWeights.Bold;
```