# how to add styles to TextBlock dynamically?

Tags: windows-8, textblock

I am developing a metro style app.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="txt_box" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White"  FontSize="20" FontFamily="Times New Roman"/>
```

In the code behind file I want to add lines of text, of which first line could be Bold, second line italics and so on..

```
 txt_box.Text = "<b>Text1</b>"
```

This doesn't work.. Any ideas how to accomplish that?

Comment: You can probably do that with Inlines. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1797958/wpf-textblock-format-text-progrmatically

Comment: If i write                                                     TextBlock t1 = new TextBlock();   t1.Inlines.Add(new Run("Hi"));             I get an error "Windows.Ui.Xaml.Documents.Run does not contain a contructor that takes 1 argument".

Comment: did you try creating a Run ([only constructor available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.run.run.aspx) is default one) then setting Text property and adding to Inlines?

Comment: Can you show me an example?