#  Font dialog and applying to TextBox text

Tags: wpf, vb.net, textbox

How to apply a specified font style selected in a font dialog to a text box in visual basic.
I'm trying to implement a notepad program that provides the ability to choose the desired font (from a list of available fonts), and then I want to apply this font to the text in the TextBox.
I have done this so far

```
        FontDialog1.ShowDialog()
        TextBox1.Font = FontDialog1.Font
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: `Foreground="HEXCODE"` for example > `Foreground="#FFAA3636"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to set all Font-related properties of the TextBox from the `System.Drawing.Font` that is returned by the [FontDialog.Font](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.fontdialog.font.aspx) property:

```
System.Drawing.Font font = fontDialog.Font;
textBox.FontFamily = new FontFamily(font.Name);
textBox.FontSize = font.Size;
textBox.FontWeight = font.Bold ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Regular;
textBox.FontStyle = font.Italic ? FontStyles.Italic : FontStyles.Normal;
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/637636/1136211).

Comment: How I can write it in Visual Basic?

Comment: Don't know VB. But is should be easy for you to find out how to set these properties, since you are the VB programmer.

Comment: I have done that, but I have missed the underline property and the Strikeout property. I'd be grateful if you could give me some help to do the remaining two actions.